# Load an MLIR file as a model using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I saved the resnet50 model like that:

```py
model = resnet.ResNet50()
model.save("resnet50”)
```

After that I translated it to tflite and then to an MLIR with these two commands:

```
tflite_convert —saved_model_dir=dir_saved_model --output_file=resnet50.tflite
bazel run //tensorflow/compiler/mlir/lite:flatbuffer_translate -- --tflite-flatbuffer-to-mlir resnet50.tflite -o resnet50.mlir
```

Now my goal is to do the opposite and reload the generate MLIR into my python code maybe with that:

```py
model = models.load_model("resnet50")
```

Or maybe with another thing I have no idea.
At the end, I would like to use it like that at the end:

```py
img = image.load_img("Panda.JPG", target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = resnet.preprocess_input(x)
predictions = model.predict(x) #use the MLIR model load in python here
predicted_classes = resnet.decode_predictions(predictions, top=9)
```

So, I just need a code to load the MLIR in my code but I couldn't find anything about it on the internet. Does anyone have any idea on how to reuse the generate MLIR in my Tensorflow code?